# Telebot how to edit message via callback

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['pages'])
def pages(m):
    mypages = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for l in usr.list:
        #how to send messageid via this callback_data?
        messageid = mypages.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(l), callback_data=str(somedata)))#+messageid  ???
        index+=1
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'TEXT', reply_markup=mypages)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_buttons(call):
    somedata = call.data
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    lst = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Something', callback_data=somenew_data), 
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Back', callback_data=somenew_data)]
    keyboard.add(*lst)
    #how to get here messageid from func pages? 
    bot.edit_message_text(message_id=messageid, text='NEW TEXT', reply_markup=keyboard)
    ...
```

I want to make editing last message(like in BotFather's menu). However, messageid(to edit this last message) i can get only after sending message(in func pages, then I want to edit this message from callback_buttons), I cant send messageid via callback_data. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the messageId and chatId from the call object.

```
chatId = call.message.chat.id
messageId = call.message.message_id
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chatId, message_id=messageId, text="Hello")
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and resolved it by positioning the parameters for the edit_message_text function in correct order like this :

```
bot.edit_message_text('NEW TEXT',chatId , messageId , reply_markup=keyboard)
```